# Nginx reverse proxy infinetly redirecting between home and login page

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a server with the following Nginx reverse proxy setup, resulting in an infinite redirection loop. I need help in correctly setting up my reverse proxy in NGINX.

I dont know what the problem is as this is the first time im setting up a reverse proxy.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen   443 default_server ssl;

    server_name 140.238.204.239;

    location /corp {
        proxy_pass https://sd3zw4pfox.adb.ap-sydney-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/r/dwh_apex/test;
    }
}
```

[image]